# How to set a CSS background to scroll slowly?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a single page design currently with background images set in CSS, with `background-position: fixed;`
This works well, but I'd like the background images to scroll, rather than being fixed - but scroll slightly, not at the same speed as the content. (Parallax)

I understand that there are several parallax solutions available, but are any of them suitable for my design without drastically changing it?

Comment: Give a try: http://www.justinmind.com/support/parallax-scrolling-speeds/

Comment: Here's a solution using only CSS http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are usng jquery.

Try this plugin:

```
(function($) {

                $.fn.parallax = function(options) {

                    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

                    // Establish default settings
                    var settings = $.extend({
                        speed        : 0.15
                    }, options);

                    // Iterate over each object in collection
                    return this.each( function() {

                        // Save a reference to the element
                        var $this = $(this);

                        // Set up Scroll Handler
                        $(document).scroll(function(){

                                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                                    var offset = $this.offset().top;
                                    var height = $this.outerHeight();

                        // Check if above or below viewport
                        if (offset + height <= scrollTop || offset >= scrollTop + windowHeight) {
                            return;
                        }

                        var yBgPosition = Math.round((offset - scrollTop) * settings.speed);

                             // Apply the Y Background Position to Set the Parallax Effect
                            $this.css('background-position', 'center ' + yBgPosition + 'px');

                        });
                    });
                }
            }(jQuery));

            $('.bg-1,.bg-3').parallax({
                speed : 0.15
            });

            $('.bg-2,.bg-4').parallax({
                speed : 0.25
            });

            $('.bg-5, .bg-7').parallax({
                speed : 0.35
            });
            $('.bg-6, .bg-8').parallax({
                speed : 0.15
            });
            $('.bg-9, .bg-11').parallax({
                speed : 0.25
            });
            $('.bg-10').parallax({
                speed : 0.35
            });
        }
```

Change your selectors (e.g. '.bg_1') according to your markup